# Javascript in Email Campaign

Tags: javascript, email, html-email, newrelic

OK we have a 3rd party development team that has created an App for us that pushes emails out for us. But we have installed New Relic on the server and turned on Browser tracking but the emails that are being generated out of that app now have the New Relic code in the head. Will this cause Deliverability issues with there being a script tag in the email being sent?

Obviously the goal is to have the developers to remove this code or we can turn off browser tracking but i was wondering if this will hurt our Deliverability with it having 2 script tags in the email.

Thanks,
T

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I would suggest taking one of the final emails and passing it through a mail analyzer (something that gives you a spam rating) and see if you're satisfied. My guess would be JS in an email would rate poorly (which is why you're generally left with images and CSS to decipher if an email's had an impression--otherwise JS would make ConstantContact's life cake).

Comment: I disable the processing of any script in emails on every system that people ask me to do work on. It is common that viruses attach scripts to emails. It makes your email extremely suspect.

Comment: To add to my comment. An image is a safer way to determine how many people opened your email on the clients side.

Comment: Yeah i understand that part about tracking there provider that send the email uses so form of a beacon. Our problem is that New Relic is injecting the code automatically like it should because we show a preview of the email (which gets the NR code) and that is what is sent to the provider that actually pushes the email. 

Good idea on running it through a scanner @BradChristie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben has an excellent answer on what will happen with the scripts.

I just want to mention on how you should remove the scripts:

Currently you can use API calls on all agents except for Node.js and Java. 
If you can run the appropriate API call when calling the preview of the pages, it will prevent the script injection.

---

Here is where you can find the documentation for each:

**PHP**: http://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-agent-api#api-rum-disable

**Ruby**: http://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/installation-and-configuration/ignoring-specific-transactions#page-load-timing-rum

**.NET**: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/features/net-agent-api#disable_browser

**Python**: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/customization-extension/python-transaction-api#disable_browser_autorum

Answer (score 2):

Well,  Gmail will strip out any content between `<script>` tags before displaying the message. It doesn't mean that your message won't be delivered, but certain clients may mark it as Spam.

Most web mail providers do this to prevent against XSS attacks.

In short, better to remove it, because the code will likely never get executed by some of the largest web and email clients around.